# WAN Failover using eth0 and wlan0

Tags: networking

I need to create a failover using wifi - connected to wireless 3G modem and lan connected to adsl router

When the Adsl goes down it needs to failover to the 3G on wlan0

I've tried many scripts online and nothing works, please send me the correct script I'll need.

PS: i need to check for hosts such as www.google.com, the failover wont be of any use if it only fails over after physically unplugging the eth cable. It must fail over if i unplug the telephone line on the router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `nmcli con list` to find out the UUID of your 3G connection and then run `sudoedit /usr/local/bin/inettest` and copy in the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

ping -I eth0 -q -c 2 8.8.4.4 > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    nmcli con down uuid 03e5a69a-2682-47df-a443-59cec06802aa
else
    nmcli con up uuid 03e5a69a-2682-47df-a443-59cec06802aa
fi
```

Replace the UUID above with yours (obviously) and save it. Run `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/inettest` to make it executable.

Test this now.

- Run `inettest` with a working `eth0` connection.
- Then break `eth0` and run it again.
- And fix it and run it again.

The 3G connection should come up and go back down. If it doesn't there's something squiffy afoot with the script. But assuming that all runs well, we can schedule it to run every 5 minutes by running `crontab -e` and adding the following on a new line:

```
*/5 * * * *    /usr/local/bin/inettest
```

You might want a tighter resolution. Cron can only schedule down to the minute but you can stack multiple calls with sleeps. This example will run twice a minute:

```
* * * * *    /usr/local/bin/inettest & sleep 30; /usr/local/bin/inettest
```

I don't think you'd want to go much tighter than that.